# Whenever I open my terminal, I get the error -bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier in ubuntu

Tags: bash, profile

Whenever I open my terminal, I get the *error-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier* in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Check your **./bash_profile** file and see if there are any **white spaces** around the **=** sign. Remove them as in the example below

```
foo = bar
```

Would become:

```
foo=bar
```

To edit this file I wouldn't recommend a normal text editor as this can use improper quote characters, use an editor like Atom.